# Can't convert "float" to "mathf" (C#)

Tags: c#

I just discovered MathF (wonderful tool). Like any new tool, we're going through some... growing pains. I'm working on unit conversion script. Here's my code. I thought MathF.Pow requires two floats, in this case 10 and 6. But apparently that's frowned upon. Any ideas?

```
Mathf megagram;


void Start () {
    megagram = Mathf.Pow(10,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Mathf.Pow` returns a `float`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Pow.html) while you are assigning the return value (`float`) to `megagram` (`MathF` type)

Answer (score 0):

```
float megagram;

void Start () 
{
    megagram = Mathf.Pow(10f,6f);
}
```

If you write `6` or `10`, compiler thinks that you use `Int32`. For floats write `f` suffix - `6f`, `10f`

Also `Mathf.Pow` returns `float`, not a `Mathf` type

Comment: That's not the point here. `Mathf.Pow` take `float` for both parameter and there is an implicit conversation from `int` to `float`. The case is `Mathf.Pow` returns `float` as well but OP try to assign it to `Mathf` type which I thing there is no way to do it for now.

Comment: @SonerGönül There is, if the Mathf type implements the overload for it :D